# Can't paste array into range with setValue()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I mapped a function to an array which is supposed to give me `Yes` or `No` depending on the input when I `Logger.log(costsfinalised)` the array I get this:

```
[No, No, No, No, Yes, No, No, Yes, Yes, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No, No]
```

But when I try to paste it with `setValues(costsfinalised)`, I get an error saying:

> 'Cannot convert Array into Object'

When I do `setValue(costsfinalised)` instead, it does work but only with `No`s (it is not really what is in the log. Why? How can I paste this array into a range?

```
var costsfinalised=sourcevalues.map(costs);

  //Logger.log();
  Logger.log(costsfinalised);

destinationsheet.getRange(2,7,costsfinalised.length,1).setValues(costsfinalised);
```

Comment: When you use the `setValues()` method, it expects you to pass a two-dimensional `Array` into it, whilst your function returns a simple `Array`. You should modify your function to return `[ [] , [] , ... ]` ( external `Array` represents rows, internal ones - columns )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**

You are trying to pass an illegal argument into the method, `setValues()` accepts only two-dimensional `Array` instances. You should treat the two-dimensional `Array` as cell mapping, where elements represent *rows* and their elements *columns*:

```
//pseudo-code;
[
 row 1 : [col1, col2],
 row 2 : [col1, col2]
]
```

**Solution**

You can modify your code to generate this `Array` for you (judging from your code, you want to populate one column, right? Regardless of that, if you add a second loop to generate column values, you will be able to populate `Range` with custom number of rows and columns):

```
var col = destinationsheet.getRange(2,7,costsfinalised.length,1);

var temp = [];

for(var i=0; i<costsfinalised.length; i++) {
  var row = [ costsfinalised[i] ];
  temp.push(row);
}

col.setValues(temp);
```

**Alternatives**

Alternatively, you can use the `map` method on your `Array` (in your case you can simply reference the `cost` instead of `costsfinalised[i]` - just don't forget to wrap it as well - `return [ cost ]`):

```
var col = destinationsheet.getRange(1,1,costsfinalised.length,1);

var output = costsfinalised.map(function (cost,i) { return [ costsfinalised[i] ]; } );

col.setValues(output);
```

**Useful links**

1. `setValues()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues);
2. `Array` built-in [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) on MDN;
3. `map()` method [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on MDN;

Comment: About the below script, for your comment of ``you can simply reference the cost instead of costsfinalised[i]``, I think that ``var output = costsfinalised.map(function (cost,i) { return [ costsfinalised[i] ]; } );`` might be ``var output = costsfinalised.map(function (cost) { return [cost] } );``. It supposes that ``costsfinalised`` is 1 dimensional array.

Comment: Hi, Tanaike, yes, I meant exactly the same (sorry for not making it clearer, ofc it should be referenced as `[cost]`) - will update the answer just in case to avoid confusion!